# Swift Error - 'Cannot invoke value of type 'SwiftStockChart.LabelForValueGetter' (aka'(CGFloat) -> String') with argument list '(Value:CGFloat)'

Tags: swift, graph, swift3, uilabel, cgfloat

I am getting two errors when I am trying to set the chart points from the Yahoo Finance API using Swift.  The first error says

'Cannot invoke value of type 'SwiftStockChart.LabelForValueGetter' (aka'(CGFloat) -> String') with argument list '(Value:CGFloat)'

this is on line

```
let text = labelForValue(value: minValue! + (maxValue! - minValue!) / CGFloat(verticalGridStep!) * CGFloat((i + 1)))
```

Then I also get an error saying

'Cannot invoke value of type 'SwiftStockChart.LabelForValueGetter' (aka'(Int) -> String') with argument list '(Value:Int)'

And this is on line

```
let text = labelForIndex(index: i)
```

The full code is:

```
func setChartPoints(points: [ChartPoint]) {

    if points.isEmpty { return }

    dataPoints = points

    computeBounds()


    if maxValue!.isNaN { maxValue = 1.0 }

    for i in 0 ..< verticalGridStep! {

        let yVal = axisHeight! + margin! - CGFloat((i + 1)) * axisHeight! / CGFloat(verticalGridStep!)
        let p = CGPoint(x: (valueLabelPosition! == .right ? axisWidth! : 0), y: yVal)

        let text = labelForValue(value: minValue! + (maxValue! - minValue!) / CGFloat(verticalGridStep!) * CGFloat((i + 1)))

        let rect = CGRect(x: margin!,  y: p.y + 2, width: self.frame.size.width - margin! * 2 - 4.0, height: 14.0)
        let width = text.boundingRect(with: rect.size,
                                      options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                      attributes:[NSFontAttributeName : valueLabelFont!],
                                      context: nil).size.width

        let xPadding = 6
        let xOffset = width + CGFloat(xPadding)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: p.x - xOffset + 5.0, y: p.y, width: width + 2, height: 14))
        label.text = text
        label.font = valueLabelFont
        label.textColor = valueLabelTextColor
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.backgroundColor = valueLabelBackgroundColor!

        self.addSubview(label)
        axisLabels.append(label)

    }

    for i in 0 ..< horizontalGridStep! + 1 {

        let text = labelForIndex(index: i)

        let p = CGPoint(x: margin! + CGFloat(i) * (axisWidth! / CGFloat(horizontalGridStep!)) * 1.0, y: axisHeight! + margin!)


        let rect = CGRect(x: margin!, y: p.y + 2, width: self.frame.size.width - margin! * 2 - 4.0, height: 14)
        let width = text.boundingRect(with: rect.size,
                                      options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                      attributes:[NSFontAttributeName : indexLabelFont!],
                                      context: nil).size.width

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: p.x - 5.0, y: p.y + 5.0, width: width + 2, height: 14))
        label.text = text
        label.font = indexLabelFont!
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = indexLabelTextColor!
        label.backgroundColor = indexLabelBackgroundColor!

        self.addSubview(label)
        axisLabels.append(label)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Guess**: You are using a code, or reading documentation, designed for a pre-Swift 3 version of SwiftStockKit.

*This is a guess as the question does not provide enough details to be sure. So this might be wrong!*

---

The Swift proposal [SE0111: Remove type system significance of function argument labels](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md) removed the significance of argument labels in function types and was implemented in Swift 3.

[SwiftStockKit](https://github.com/ackleymi/SwiftStock/blob/master/SwiftStockKit.swift) as currently on the web defines `labelForValue` using:

```
typealias LabelForValueGetter = (value: CGFloat) -> String
var labelForValue: LabelForValueGetter!
```

this will not compile under Swift 3, it must be changed (as a compiler error instructs) to:

```
typealias LabelForValueGetter = (_ value: CGFloat) -> String
var labelForValue: LabelForValueGetter!
```

Now look at your error:

> Cannot invoke value of type 'SwiftStockChart.LabelForValueGetter' (aka'(CGFloat) -> String') with argument list '(Value:CGFloat)

The first type here has no argument label, the argument list you are supplying does - so a mismatch, remove the label in the argument list.

If you are using a copy of SwiftStockKit that has been updated for Swift 3 but you are coding for an earlier version you'll probably get a lot more errors than the 2 you report here.

HTH

Comment: This has fixed the first error but not the second? Do you have any suggestions about the let text = labelForIndex(index: i) ?

Comment: It is the same issue, just with a different function type. There could easily be more, you could maybe compare (diff/FileMerge) the source of the SwiftStockKit you are using against the one linked above, as I'm guessing your documentation is for the (pre Swift 3) web version.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you're trying to divide a string by a CGFloat.

This line

```
let text = labelForValue(value: minValue! + (maxValue! - minValue!) / CGFloat(verticalGridStep!) * CGFloat((i + 1)))
```

has a type structure of:

```
String/CGFloat * CGFloat
```

What exactly are you trying to do with that line? I can edit my answer with a solution if you can give me some more context. Also would you be willing to link to the library you're using.

Comment: I am trying to set chart points on a graph from the Yahoo API using Alamofire

Comment: What is the divid for though? Are you trying to divide the floats then turn them into a string?

Comment: Do you want me to share the code and then you can have a look